# Solving TSP on real hardware

Tags: qiskit, optimization

I'm trying to solve the traveling salesman problem using Qiskit. Following the relevant tutorial, I end up with an algorithm that uses $n^2$ qubits. This grows rapidly enough that I couldn't possibly solve even a tiny graph on real hardware available today.

If I'm willing to give up getting an "exact" solution, are there methods that would reduce the number of qubits? If not, what about this problem requires so many qubits?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi and welcome to Quantum Computing SE. Could you please provide link to the *relevant tutorial*?

Comment: Sure, https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-optimization/blob/main/docs/tutorials/06_examples_max_cut_and_tsp.ipynb

Comment: Could you add the link to the tutorial in your post instead of in a comment?